# How can I know my website contains Malicious code

Tags: security

Recently our website got hacked by some people and it is reporting as below when we try to open our website

Reported Attack Page!

This web page at www.example.com has been reported as an attack page and has been blocked based on your security preferences.

Attack pages try to install programs that steal private information, use your computer to attack others, or damage your system.Some attack pages intentionally distribute harmful software, but many are compromised without the knowledge or permission of their owners.

At Last I came to know there is some malicious code so that it is reporting in this way...
so how can i know where is that code

Comment: I have seen also standard java libraries being infected (larger file sizes). This means, check your local pcs too. Best kill the machine and start afresh with other passwords etc, shell with key pairs. Scan the database for anomalies: `<script`, `%[hex][hex]` (encoded HTML).

Comment: i didn't got what you said

Comment: Sorry, basically I meant, after having found how they did it, reinstall the server. And then use key files instead of passwords for a remote shell. Disable FTP. And check the database for hidden javascripting hacks (`<`, `%3c`, `%3C`).

Comment: Your question seems to be off topic for Stack Overflow, since it's not primarily about programming. You might get better answers to it on our sister sites, http://security.stackechange.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if someone had already asked the same question there before.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, first, scan your own PC to ensure the infection did not originate there.
Then download the site to a safe location(you may need to disable your antivirus software for a while for the purpose). Hopefully you have a backup of the original site before infection(or your webhosting partner). Make a compare against the infected content and you should clearly see the difference.

If you do not have a backup, scan the infected scripts with antivirus software to determine specific files, then you need to browse through the code in these files and scan for malicious code manually. Those worms/trojans mostly append to file, or specific tag, look for suspicious lines and parts of code that do not look familiar.

Comment: how to know the infected scripts...wen i scanned whole project there is no malware it is showing...

Comment: Asuming you used latest anti-virus with update database, try searching for the patterns mentioned above(preferably using regex) - 
< %lt; $gt; %digit etc.